# Настройка кнопок соц. сетей через API yandex.share2

Tags: ya-share2

```
<title>Site &mdash; Новости</title>    
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=htmlspecialchars($result[0]['title'])?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($result[0]['description']))?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" />
<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js">   </script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>

<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"></div>
```

Проблема в том, что в Диалоговом окне vkontakte, не правильно отображается Заголовок, подхватывается текст из обычного `<title>` , а не из мета-тега `og:title`.
В диалоговое окно facebook вообще попадает только текст из обычного `<title>`, отсутствуют: `og:description`, `img`.
А вот диалоговое окно `odnoklassniki` работает как положено с  `og:title`, `og:description`, и все картинки попадают.

Подскажите как исправить эти недочеты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь отладчиком для FB: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
Скорее всего, у вас закэшировалась старая версия, поэтому нажмите "scrape again", если видите некорректные данные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону документации 
https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/

Для переопределения title используйте аттрибут `data-title`

Для description используйте `data-description`

А для изображения `data-image`

Comment: facebook вообще ни на что не реагирует, ни на data атрибуты, не на семантическую разметку.